# Need to trigger a count when certain value is reached

Tags: excel

i have a school project and some help would be very appreciated, i have a list of -1,0 and 1's in a column in chronological order, i need a formula that starts counting when it hits the value (1) and then continues counting regardless if it is 0 or 1, but end the count when the value is (-1). I've been researching on how to do this and can't figure it out. thank you in advance

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTkEZ.png)

Comment: Please show a sample table, what the sample output would be, and explain the step-by-step process for how you would come up with the final answer.  As it stands, your explanation isn't very clear, and would probably have a lot of follow-up Q&A.  Consider reading [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: thanks i posted a picture of what the dataset looks like (if you look a the trade column this is the dataset my question is about)

Answer (score 0):

With the column of numbers starting in A2, put this formula into B2 and copy down.

```
=IF(AND(A2=1,B1=""),1,IF(A2<0,"",IF(ISNUMBER(B1),SUM(B1,1),"")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This formula counts the number of rows between the first occurrence of '1' and the next occurrence of '-1', assuming your data starts in row 1 of column A.

```
=MATCH(-1,INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(1,A:A,0)&":A1000"),0)
```

This is based on the sub-formula `=MATCH(1,A:A,0)` which finds the first occurrence of '1' in column A. The rest of the formula finds the first occurrence of '-1' in the rows below where '1' was found.

[image: Formula example]

Comment: i tried to use the formula but for some reason it gives me a value of 3 everywhere, any idea why?

Comment: You might want to check the range your values are in. This formula is specifically designed for values which start in A1.

Comment: yes i placed them in A1  but still gives me 3's, i will try to solve this but if you can think of another reason why let me know thanks

Comment: Could you post a picture of your results or a link to your file?